# laravel voyager subdomain image not showing

Tags: laravel, filesystems, voyager

voyager project is installed on a subdomaine. https://sub.domainname.com/ ,
There is no problem in uploading images in local and I can show them But when i try it on hosting, the pictures appear broken, no matter what i did

APP URL

```
APP_URL=https://sub.domainname.com
```

Config/fileSystems

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
    ],

],
```

after uploading an image its image on the media menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYwXQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish the storage folder link? `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: yes but no change

Comment: Did you try clearing cache? Like `php artisan optimize:clear` or `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: yes i tried it too

Comment: If you click on the public link the image is shown in the browser?

Comment: no i can't see it at all i get 404 error

Comment: Please, check in your URL if there are backslashes (\) instead of forward slashes (/). Sometimes webservers, specially shared hostings, adds backslashes to the URLs when saving and they don't render them once they're loaded. If so (if you they have backslashes and you can see images by changing them to forward slashes) then you can override Voyager to improve this behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be a problem. I upload the image from my subdomain project to the `public_html` directory in the root directory, but when I want to access the image, I get a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

### Update Question

I'm uploading from my subdomain project to the storage folder in the root directory
this way I created a voyager storage in

```
'voyager' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => '/home/username/public_html/storage/app/public',
            'url' => 'https://website.com/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ]
```

In my config/voyager.php file, I gave the disk I created custom.

```
'storage' => [
        'disk' => 'voyager',
    ],
```

In this way, I can send images to the root directory of the project under public_html, but my images are still not visible on voyager.
The path of the images looks like this;

```
https://website.com/storage/works/July2022/5w9ONuhB1VgQFLj9hGJH.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but is all your code inside the public_html folder? I mean, is there all including routes, storage, app, etc.?

This may affect the way your application considers where is the public folder. So you can open Tinker or add a log to see if the public_path() function is returning the correct path. If not, then you should instruct your application to redirect the path to the right folder or change the structure of your project to one more convenient/secure.

Also is the one from the example the subdomain? As it looks like a main domain.

PS: I don't know much about the cons, but most people doesn't recommend exposing paths here, like your project's domain or structure, as you don't know what can people do with that information.